# How to generate non-recurring numbers from the range JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, unique

I have array with 10 items, I calls one random item using a random number from 1 to 10, what to use to make a random number from 1 to 10, which will not happen again, and when all 10 is used, the program stops randomly? [code](https://jsfiddle.net/zxzc0/rg95yf02/112/)

```
const num = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  const postWord = () => {
    randomWord = word.innerText = words[num()].PL;
  }

  postWord();

  submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
    postWord();
  });
```

Comment: So you basically want to [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) the array?

Comment: Yeah, that's a *random order* of a fixed list of numbers, not a list of *random numbers*.

Comment: I'm not sure how the program "stops randomly" after a list of exactly 10 non-repeating numbers has been used. Sounds like it will pretty predictably stop after exactly 10 numbers.

Comment: This program is about the number of words (10 for example). One word is random and you have to translate it, and if you translate it, the next one is drawn, and when the words end, the game is over. 
But in total with this end of the program I can do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered to move the array items?

```
var range = 10; // global variable

const num = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
  const postWord = () => {
    randomWord = word.innerText = words[num()].PL;
    for (var i=num(); i < range; i++) {
        var temp = words[i];
        words[i] = words[i+1];
        words[i+1] = temp;
    }
    range--;
  }

  postWord();

  submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (range) {
      postWord();
    }
  });
```

I am not that familiar with JS but I guess my code can at least demonstrate my point.